# If two plotted meshes of nonlinear equations in a system intersect, does that mean there are always infinite solutions?

Tags: nonlinear-system

I am trying to wrap my head around this, as I have no formal education on it.  I have a system of two nonlinear equations, with two variables.  If I plot them in Matlab/Octave, and get two intersecting meshes, does that mean all the points where the meshes intersect are solutions to the system of equations?  Does this mean any system like this that intersects has infinite solutions?  If this is the case, how would I write the solution to the system if there are infinite possibilities?  Is there some special notation?

Thanks for any replies!